# Issue in getting the individual data parameters from the json.JsonArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am receiving the data from the `api` but the code following do not work for some reason

Here is the code:

```
 ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(newFixedThreadPool(50));
                final ListenableFuture<JsonElement> userfromapi = mClient.invokeApi("userinfo",null, "GET", null);
                Futures.addCallback(userfromapi, new FutureCallback<JsonElement>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final JsonElement result) {
                        final JsonArray contacts = result.getAsJsonArray();
                            final String jsonString = contacts.getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();
                            final String facebookid = contacts.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("id").getAsString();
                            final String name = contacts.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("first_name" + "last_name").toString();
                            final String imgurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookid + "/picture";

                    }
```

The problem is that, after the success call back getting the individual ids, name, etc

Comment: i am  having the problem can anyone help me too
here is my code
 `final JsonArray contacts = result.getAsJsonArray();
  final String facebookid = contacts.getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsString();`

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: thankyou for the reply but i have solved it by making a model class

Answer (score 0):

Make model class- For e.g

public class MyClass{

```
@SerializedName("Name")
private String Name;

public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

for e.g Fetch data like this -

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                MyClass myClassModel = new Gson().
                                        fromJson(jsonObject.get("JsonArrayName").toString(),
                                                new TypeToken<MyClass>() {
                                                }.getType());
```

Comment: thankyou very much , i have done the same way and it worked

Comment: Dhanshri i am having a problem in inserting data in azure data base as           ' User entity ;
        entity = mUser.insert(items).get();' and the name in items is been sent null but other values are sent as it is